# How to subset dataframe based on specific combination of factors across two columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

```
sp1.col <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C")
sp1.val <- c(1:12)
sp2.col <- c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D")
sp2.val <- c(1:12)

df <- data.frame(sp1.col, sp1.val, sp2.col, sp2.val)
```

I want subset the data-frame such that sp1 and sp2 have identical species names, and all other rows are eliminated.

So the final dataframe should look like

```
   sp1.col sp1.val sp2.col sp2.val
       A      1       A      1
       B      5       B      5
       C      11      C      11
```

Comment: @akrun Apologies. Corrected it now

Comment: Based on your example, I get 6 instead of 5 for the second row `subset(df, sp1.col == sp2.col)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `subset` in `base R` (no packages needed)

```
subset(df, sp1.col == sp2.col)
```

-output

```
  sp1.col sp1.val sp2.col sp2.val
1        A       1       A       1
6        B       6       B       6
11       C      11       C      11
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> with(df,df[sp1.col==sp2.col,])
   sp1.col sp1.val sp2.col sp2.val
1        A       1       A       1
6        B       6       B       6
11       C      11       C      11
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(sp1.col == sp2.col)
```